# Update location from text file in Google Earth Pro in real time?

Tags: google-earth, import, google-earth-pro

I'm trying to update the ship's location from a text file in Google Earth Pro in real-time. The Lon/Lat locations of the ship are being written to a text file from the GPS.

I am new to using Google Earth Pro.

Comment: you will need to create a network kml in order to see the updates almost real-time https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference?csw=1#networklinkcontrol

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the format of your "text file".  If it's being written as KML, then you should be able to point to that file with a NetworkLink as Mapperz mentioned. If it's in another format, then you'll likely need to convert the data to KML first.  Alternatively, it's possible to get a NMEA formatted feed from the GPS unit, then you should be able to feed that directly into Google Earth Pro using the GPS tools.  More details in Google Earth's "Real-time GPS Tracking" documentation, here: https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148095